# why subscribe function is not called in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

I am using observable in angular .Actually my issue when I click button my `subscribe` function not called why ?
as per documentation `subscribe` function will call when we call `next` function

https://plnkr.co/edit/83NaHoVaxiXAeUFoaEmb?p=preview

```
constructor() {
  this.data = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer);
  this.data.subscribe(value => {
    console.log('+++')
    console.log(value)
  })
}

hndle(){
  this.name.push({name:"navee"});

  this.dataObserver.next(this.name);
}
```

here is documentation

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/tutorial.html

Comment: When do you call hndle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On basis of Volodymyr Bilyachat suggestion i have modified your code. its working now plz check. Problem was in your way of using dataObserver

```
     //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
      <li *ngFor ="let n of name">{{n.name}}</li>
      </ul>
      <button (click)="hndle()">heelo</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  private data:Observable;
  private dataObserver:Observer;
  name:string;
  name[];
  constructor() {
        this.dataObserver = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer);
 this.dataObserver.subscribe(value => {
    console.log('+++')
    console.log(value)
  });
  }

  hndle(){

    this.name.push({name:"navee"});

    this.dataObserver.next(this.name);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

link https://plnkr.co/edit/PO80y2udrOhsVq4QQXc5?p=preview

Comment: this.dataObserver = observer - this part should set correctly

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat thanks for telling this. i was just trying to help :) i have modified my answer

Comment: @amit what are changes you did

Comment: @user944513 1) i have changed *ngFor=let n of data with *ngFor ="let n of name" ii) you have not declared any data variable but you we storing you observalbe in it this.data = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer);  i replaced it with  this.dataObserver = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer); plz check my  plnkr once more

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's better to use this solution:

```
constructor() {
    this.data = new Subject();

    this.data.subscribe(value => {
        console.log('+++');
        console.log(value);
    });
}

hndle() { // TYPO: Probably it was meant to be handle
    this.name.push({ 
        name: 'navee'
    });

    this.data.next(this.name);
}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
```

Working example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zB8FHTVEm2QUHiEAYuQB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are subscribing to the observable 2 times. You should be able to fix it by adding .share()

```
constructor() {

    this.data = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer).share();
   this.data.subscribe(value => {
    console.log('+++')
    console.log(value)

  })
  }

  hndle(){
    this.name.push({name:"navee"});

    this.dataObserver.next(this.name);
  }
```